# how to stop redirection in wishlist (i am using a custom plugin)

Tags: php, extensions, magento-1, wishlist

I am using a plugin called ajaxwishlist, which gives facility to add to compare and wishlist, everything is working fine but I want to stop the redirection.

I also put an if condition to check wether they are logged in but it is also now working.

The code below is in `ajaxwishlist_indexcontroller.php`:

```
protected function _getWishlist()
{
    $wishlist = Mage::registry('wishlist');
    if ($wishlist) {
        return $wishlist;
    }

    try {
        $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')
        ->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer(), true);
        Mage::register('wishlist', $wishlist);
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/session')->addException($e,
        Mage::helper('wishlist')->__('Cannot create wishlist.')
        );
        return false;
    }

    return $wishlist;
}
public function addAction()
{

    $response = array();
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('wishlist/general/active')) {
        $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
        $response['message'] = $this->__('Wishlist Has Been Disabled By Admin');
    }
    if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
        $response['message'] = $this->__('Please Login First');
    }

    if(empty($response)){
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $wishlist = $this->_getWishlist();
        if (!$wishlist) {
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $this->__('Unable to Create Wishlist');
        }else{

            $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
            if (!$productId) {
                $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('Product Not Found');
            }else{

                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                if (!$product->getId() || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
                    $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                    $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot specify product.');
                }else{

                    try {
                        $requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
                        $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($requestParams);

                        $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
                        if (is_string($result)) {
                            Mage::throwException($result);
                        }
                        $wishlist->save();

                        Mage::dispatchEvent(
                            'wishlist_add_product',
                        array(
                            'wishlist'  => $wishlist,
                            'product'   => $product,
                            'item'      => $result
                        )
                        );

                        Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();

                        $message = $this->__('%1$s has been added to your wishlist.', $product->getName(), $referer);
                        $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                        $response['message'] = $message;

                        Mage::unregister('wishlist');

                        $this->loadLayout();
                        $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
                        $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('wishlist_sidebar');
                        $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                        $response['toplink'] = $toplink;
                        $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
                    }
                    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                        $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                        $response['message'] = $this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist: %s', $e->getMessage());
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        mage::log($e->getMessage());
                        $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                        $response['message'] = $this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist.');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
    return;
}
```

}